# c++ createprocess as administrator and get its output

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess, shellexecuteex

I have a problem, I have been looking for two things that must go together, running a process through `Createprocess()` as an administrator and get the output.

When I Google how to `CreateProcess()` as an administrator I get people replying to use `shellexecute`.  I go to `shellexecute`, while I am there, shellexecute does not output what ran on the console(process).

I Google again how do I get the output of a process with shellexecute, I get answers that say you cannot do that with shellexecute, use createprocess, so I go to createprocess.  I am struggling to convert what I am doing with shellexecute to createprocess.

What I am doing with shellexecute does what I am looking for, run as administrator. but no output.

Here is my shellexecute code.

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO si = {0};

si.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
si.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
si.hwnd =NULL;
si.lpVerb = "runas";
si.lpFile = "netsh.exe";
si.lpParameters = "advfirewall firewall      add rule name=\"dummy_rule\" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=3300";
si.lpDirectory=NULL;
si.nShow=SW_SHOW;
si.hInstApp =NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&si);
WaitForSingleObject(si.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(si.hProcess);
```

This code runs in a method and what it does is add a firewall rule to open a port for imcoming connections. It is working fine as it is, the problem is I won't know whether the process was successfull, not shellexecute. so I need output.

Comment: Hello, could you find any solution for your this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is actually Creates two process `runas.exe` and `netsh.exe` , where it could create only one instead . The right way of doing that would be:

1. Use `LogonUser()` functions with the Administrator credentials, to get an administrative token.
2. Call `CreateProcessAsUser()` with your IO redirection **and** the above token.

note that for `CreateProcessAsUser()` you should specify `netsh.exe` as the process you'd like to execute, and your argument in `LPTSTR lpCommandLine`.

Comment: since i will not be knowing who in that computer is allowed to run administrative tasks, how would i login the appropriate user without knowing the username and their password

Comment: well, you just have to know. otherwise it won't make sense that you're running privileged code.

Comment: but sir you know there are applications that will prompt the administrator's username and password. they dont know who the admin is but they request whoever is the admin to come out and authorise, that would be better, rather than write username and password in the source code

Comment: of course. you can have the user inserting the credentials as an input argument to you application, or , in case of a `GUI` application, prompt a form for it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `CreateProcessElevated()` function from this article:

[Vista UAC: The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide)

It has the same features as `CreateProcess()` but offers the `runas` functionality of `ShellExecute()`, ie prompting the user for the UAC elevation credentials.